# Reading and Printing a string inassembly

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I'm trying to learn the functions in the Irvine library. Right now, I am trying to create a simple code which asks for a string to be entered, and then is supposed to print it out along with a message.

Not really sure where I went wrong. All I know is that when I run the following code, it accepts the input, prints it out again on the following line (without the first character), and then prints it again fully on the line after that.

It also totally ignores enteredStringDisplay.

Any hints in where

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

enterString BYTE "Please enter the string to print: ", 0
enteredString BYTE ?
enteredStringDisplay BYTE "You entered: ", 0

.code
main proc

mov edx, offset enterString
call WriteString
mov  ecx,32     
mov  edx,offset enteredString 
call ReadString

mov edx, offset enteredStringDisplay
call WriteString
call crlf
mov edx, offset enteredString
call WriteString
call crlf
exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: You only reserved 1 byte of space for your input string, so user input overwrites `enteredStringDisplay`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I feel dumb. Thank you for pointing that out. It works now (naturally).

Comment: It often helps to use a debugger.  You might have noticed that the pointer addresses only differed by one, or you could have checked memory contents.  This is why it's a good idea to put read-only string in a different section.  IDK what you can can do with MASM on Windows, but on Linux `section .rodata` is the best choice for read-only data.  That section becomes part of the text segment (along with the executable code).

Comment: Anyway, nice job describing the behaviour you were seeing accurately enough.  Even though the answer turned out to be trivial, this is a pretty well-asked question with a [mcve], not a giant wall of code.  Welcome to Stack Overflow :)